# Remove and add object (Key, value) in array

Tags: powershell

I have a JSON file which has some 2 values like below

[image]

I want to remove the part where name = "yname" and add a new part in there. Finally update my json file.

What I tried:

With below command, I was able to remove but how do I add new part with new key value pairs?

```
 $JobOutput.connectionstrings = $JobOutput.connectionstrings | Where-Object name -ne "yname"
```

Comment: I think something like `$JobOutput.connectionstrings = @($JobOutput.connectionstrings) + [pscustomobject]@{name = 'zname'; BaseAddress = 'zaddress'; ClientId = 'zclientid'}` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AdminOfThings - Thanks, that worked! I was not aware of that syntax.